# Tiebreaking in Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch

If I'm making queries to ElasticSearch using a custom score filter, how does it handle the case when documents have the same score?

Are they returned in the order they were inserted, or can I specify how the case should be handled?

Ideally I'd like them to be returned in a random order if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now you are sorting by `_score`. So, you can add a second sort key that will contain a script with random number generator. See [Random order & pagination Elasticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9796470/random-order-pagination-elasticsearch) for a couple of different examples.