# How to make 2 groups in random order in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

For example, in google.com, there are 2 type of search results, 1. Ads that relevant to keyword and 2. normal search result.

How can I do that with Elastic search with following conditions

1. Show Ads for 3 slots with random by userid in a top 3 in search result
2. Show normal search result that also random by userid

How to make a single query to integrate those two conditions together in search result.

Given sample data, query with 'a' then it should return random(paid 1-3) then follow by random(normal 4-6)

```
{"type" : "paid", "document" : "paid random 1"}
{"type" : "paid", "document" : "paid random 2"}
{"type" : "paid", "document" : "paid random 3"}
{"type" : "normal", "document" : "normal random 4"}
{"type" : "normal", "document" : "normal random 5"}
{"type" : "normal", "document" : "normal random 6"}
```

Comment: have you tried, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9796470/random-order-pagination-elasticsearch for getting random results??

Comment: Hi, that will be query for only single group. Already tried that. :)

Comment: so, you want to get top3 for searched item, and other three items (random) in a single request ?? do you have any query you tried ??

Comment: let say top3 is random paid search results. and below of that is random normal search result. I cannot find the way to make subquery like that.

Comment: So, search query is same? ?

Answer (score 0):

Hi looking at your question, 
I guess you are trying to fetch documents.

1. Top three random documents based on paid amount
2. Top three random documents (default)

So, I've managed to make a request for you, 
I've used [top_hits](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html) aggregation,

Here is the request,

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/x3/_search" -d'
{
   "query": {
      "match": {
         "doc": "xxx"
      }
   },
   "aggs": {
      "tophits_random_paid": {
         "top_hits": {
            "from": 0,
            "size": 3,
            "sort": [
               {
                  "paidAmount": {
                     "order": "desc"
                  }
               },
               {
                  "_script": {
                     "script": "(doc[\"userid\"].value + salt).hashCode()",
                     "type": "number",
                     "params": {
                        "salt": "some_random_string"
                     },
                     "order": "asc"
                  }
               }
            ]
         }
      },
      "tophits_random_default": {
         "top_hits": {
            "from": 0,
            "size": 3,
            "sort": [
               {
                  "_script": {
                     "script": "(doc[\"userid\"].value + salt).hashCode()",
                     "type": "number",
                     "params": {
                        "salt": "some_random_string"
                     },
                     "order": "asc"
                  }
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   }
}'
```

Thanks, Hope this helps !!.