# Elastic Search: aggregation random order?

Tags: elasticsearch

is it possible to have aggregations with a random order?
It seems that there is only asc or desc possible?

```
{
"aggs" : {
    "genders" : {
        "terms" : {
            "field" : "gender",
            "order" : { 
                "_count" : "asc" 
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible. Did it this way:

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "genders": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "gender",
        "size": 10,
        "order": {
          "rnd.max": "asc"
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "rnd": {
          "stats": {
            "script": "Math.random()"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm using the stats-aggregation here as my random-number-generator, as it has a script-property, but any other metrics-aggregation with a script-property should do it also.
You can play with the size-property of the terms-aggregation to control the number of buckets returned. The smaller the value is, the faster the aggregation runs.

Comment: From my tests, this does not work so well, at least not when `_count` between buckets vary a lot (I have buckets with count between 1 and 50.000). It generates one random value per doc, then sort the entire bucket using the max random value generated in that bucket. That means bigger buckets have bigger chance of having random values closer to 1, and tend to be on the bottom. So, _some_ randomness happens, but it's heavily influenced by `_count`. I considered using `avg`, but something similar would happen: buckets with high counts would tend to the middle and small ones would be at bottom/top

Comment: Hm, good point! My customer didn't complain about that (until now), but it seems quite plausible to me. Have to think about that again. Maybe we need something to (de-)normalize the random-numbers to the count of documents in a bucket. I think, your attempt using 'avg' points in that direction, right? Could you please share your query with me?

Answer (score 1):

Nope, according to the [official documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.5/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation-order), terms aggregations are always sorted one way or another. If not specified, aggregated terms are sorted by count descending.

If at all needed, you can always shuffle the results on the client-side in some random order, though.

Comment: Hello, Val! Do you think there is a workaround how to do that?

Comment: how about putting script in aggs i.e.

{
   "aggs" : {
       "tags" : {
           "terms":{
               "script" : {
                   "inline": "Math.sin(33*(double)doc['gender'].value) + '_' + doc['gender'].value",
                   "lang": "painless",
                   "order" : { "_term" : "desc" }
               }
           }
       }
   }
}

Comment: this would randomize the aggregation values

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can show random results
refer to the answer provided here:
[Random order & pagination Elasticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9796470/random-order-pagination-elasticsearch)

You can try something like this. I wanted to randomize the results inside buckets so I have used it.

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "genders": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "gender"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "search_second": {
          "top_hits": {
            "sort": {
              "_script": {
                "script": "Math.random()",
                "type": "number",
                "params": {},
                "order": "asc"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello, Nakul91! I am not sure that your answer answers the question directly. It was asked how to order terms aggregation buckets randomly, but in your answer you show how to sort the inner hits inside a bucket. Those are different things.