# ElasticSearch return aggregations random order

Tags: elasticsearch

I've got the following ElasticSearch-query, to get 10 documents from each "category" grouped on "cat.id":

```
"aggs": {
    "test": {
        "terms": {
            "size": 10,
            "field": "cat.id"
        },
        "aggs": {
            "top_test_hits": {
                "top_hits": {
                    "_source": {
                        "includes": [
                            "id"
                        ]
                    },
                    "size": 10
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is working fine. However I cannot seem to find a way, to randomly take 10 results from each bucket. The results are always the same. And I would like to have 10 random items from each bucket. I tried all kinds of things which are intended for documents, but non of them seem to be working.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Elastic Search: aggregation random order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30466664/elastic-search-aggregation-random-order)

Answer (score 0):

As was already suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33235619/5095957), you can try using random sort in the [`top_hits`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.3/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html#_options_2) aggregation, using a [`_script`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.3/search-request-sort.html#_script_based_sorting) like this:

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "test": {
      "terms": {
        "size": 10,
        "field": "cat.id"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "top_test_hits": {
          "top_hits": {
            "_source": {
              "includes": [
                "id"
              ]
            },
            "size": 10,
            "sort": {
              "_script": {
                "type": "number",
                "script": {
                  "lang": "painless",
                  "source": "(System.currentTimeMillis() + doc['_id'].value).hashCode()"
                },
                "order": "asc"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Random sorting was broadly covered in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9796470/random-order-pagination-elasticsearch).

Hope that helps!