# ElasticSearch random score combined with boost?

Tags: elasticsearch, random

I am building a iOS app with Firebase, and using ElasticSearch as a search engine to get more advanced queries.

I am trying to achieve a system where I can get a random record from the index, based on a query. I have already got this working using the "random_score" function with a seed.

So all documents should right now have equal chance of being selected. Is it possible to add a boost or something(sorry, I am new to ES)?

Let's say the the document has the field "boost_enabled" and it set to true, the document will be 3 times more likely to be selected, so "increasing" the chance of being selected as a random?

So in theory it should look like this:

Documents that matches the query:

```
"document1"
"document2"
"document3"
```

They all have an equal chance of being selected (33%)

What I wish to achieve is if "document1" has the field "boost_enabled" = true

It should look like this:

```
"document1"
"document1"
"document1"
"document2"
"document3"
```

So now "document1" is 3 times more likely to be selected as the random record.

Would really appreciate some help.

EDIT:

I've come up with something like this, is this correct or not? I am pretty sure it's not though...

```
"query" : {
        "function_score": {
            "query": {
                "bool" : {
                    "must": {
                        "match_all": {}
                    },
                    "should": [
                        { "exists" : {
                            "field" : "boost_enabled",
                            "boost" : 3
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                    "filter" : filterArray
                 }
            },

            "functions": [
                {
                    "random_score": {"seed": seed}
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

/ Mads

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Elasticsearch has something like that - refer to [Elasticsearch: Query-Time Boosting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/query-time-boosting.html).

In your case, you would have a portion of your query that notes the presence of the flag you described and this "subquery" would have a boost.  `bool` with its `should` clause will probably be useful.

NB: This is not EXACTLY like being able to say matching document is `n` times as likely to be a result

EDITS:

--

EDIT 1:

Elasticsearch will tell you how it comes up with the score via the 
[Explain API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-explain.html) which might be helpful in tweaking parameters.

--

EDIT 2:

I apologize for what I had posted above.  Upon further thought and exploration, I think the `boost` parameter is not quite what is required here.  `function_score` already has the notion of weight but even that falls short.  I have found other users with requirements similar to yours but it looks like there haven't been any good solutions proposed for this.

References:

- [Elasticsearch Github Issue on Weighted Random Sampling](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/7783#issuecomment-64880008)
- [Stackoverflow Post with a Request Identical to Github Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34128770/weighted-random-sampling-in-elasticsearch)

I do not think the solutions proposed in those posts are quite right.  I put together a quick shell script hitting the Elasticsearch REST API and relying on `jq` (a popular CLI for processing JSON) to demonstrate: [Github Gist: Flawed Attempt At Weighed Random Sampling with Elasticsearch](https://gist.github.com/eemp/30421b784fc7f761c3e890b3dbd14d46)

In the script, `featured_flag` is equivalent to your `boost_enabled`, and `undesired_flag` is there to demonstrate how to only consider a subset of documents in the index.  You can copy the script tweak global variables at the top of the script like Elasticsearch server, index, etc to try it out.
Some notes on the script:

- script creates one document with `featured_flag` enabled and one document with `undesired_flag` enabled that should not be ever chosen
- `TOTAL_DOCUMENTS` can be used to adjust how many total documents are created (including the first two created)
- `FEATURED_FLAG_WEIGHT` is the weight applied at query time via `function_score`
- script reruns the same query 1000 times and outputs stats on how many times each of the created documents was returned as the first result

I would imagine your index has many "featured" or "boosted" samples among many that are not.  With the described requirements, the probability of choosing a sample depends on weight of the document (let's say 3 for boosted documents, 1 for the rest) and the sum of weights across all valid documents that you want taken into consideration.  Therefore, it seems like simple weights, boosts, and randoms are just insufficient

A lot of people have considered and posted solutions for the task of weighted random sampling without Elasticsearch. This appears to be a good stab at explaining a few approaches: [electric monk: Weighted Random Distribution](https://www.electricmonk.nl/log/2009/12/23/weighted-random-distribution).  A lot of algorithmic details may not be quite relevant here but I thought they were interesting.

I think the ideal solution would require work to be done outside of Elasticsearch (without delving into creating Elasticsearch plugins, scorers, etc).  Here is the best that I can come up with at the moment:

- A numeric weight field stored in the documents (can continue with boolean fields but this seems more flexible)
- Hit Elasticsearch with an initial query leveraging aggregations for some stats we need

  - Possibly a [sum aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-sum-aggregation.html) for the sum of weights required for document probabilities
  - A [terms aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) to get counts of documents by weights (ex: `m` documents with weight 1, `n` documents with weight 3)
- Outside of Elasticsearch (in the app), choose the sample

  - generate a random number within the range of 0 to `sum_of_weights`-1
  - use the aggregation results and the generated random to select an index (see the algorithmic solutions for weighted random sampling outside of Elasticsearch) that is in the range of 0 to `total_valid_documents`-1 (call this `selected_index`)
- Hit Elasticsearch a second time with appropriate filters for considering only valid documents, a `sort` parameter that guarantees the document set is ordered the same way each time we run this process (perhaps sorted by weight and by document id), and a `from` parameter set to the `selected_index`

Slightly related to all this, I posted a slightly different [write up](http://eemp.io/2017/07/29/weighted-random-sampling-in-elasticsearch/).

Comment: But, would it give me a similiar effect, or would it be totally unrealistic?

Comment: I think you would have to experiment to see if it works out.  I think it should work out with the right weight chosen for random and the right boost.  Take a look at the "explain" functionality / Elasticsearch's explanation for the score assigned to help you out if you haven't yet found that.

Comment: Thanks alot for the help. I've added the query to the post, is this how I should be doing it?

Comment: That resembles what I had in mind.  I think another thing you might want to experiment with, while working with the Explain API, is how combinations of `random_score`, `weight`, `boost_mode`, and `score_mode` work together.   Taking a closer look at the `function_score` documentation, there is likely a possible route without query boosting, without core Elasticsearch similarity scoring, and just `function_score` scoring.  I will try to update my answer with more details on this.

Comment: Hey thank you! - The current problem I have with the query I specified is that if the field does not exist in any document, the query doesn't return any documents. I still want to be able to have other documents, just give documents who have this field a higher "chance" of being selected. Could you try and edit my query, to what you feel like it should actually be? - All other filters and queries should match. The app shows the user a random document put up by other users. If the user has applied a boost to that document, it should be "boosted", more people will see it faster. So prioritized

Comment: What if you add `minimum_should_match: 0` to the bool?

Comment: @MadsOdgaard I updated my post with further notes and perhaps a more ideal solution and I apologize for the initial misleading post :(

Answer (score 2):

In ES 7.15 i use {script_score} key, below you can see my example.

This code `"source": "_score + Math.random()"` added random 0.0 -> 1.0 number to my native boosted score. For more information you can [see this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-script-score-query.html#random-score-function)

```
{
    "size": { YOUR_SIZE_LIMIT },
    "query": {
        "script_score": {
            "query": {
                "query_string": {
                    "fields": [
                        "{ YOUR_FIELD_1 }^6",
                        "{ YOUR_FIELD_2 }^3",
                    ],
                    "query": "{ YOUR_SEARCH_QUERY }"
                }
            },
            "script": {
                "source": "_score + Math.random()"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).